# jQuery :nth-child selecting just one?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
$('.mydiv ul li:nth-child(4)').addClass("nth");
```

There are atleast 8 `li`'s in there but it only selects 4th but not 8th?

Comment: why would it select the 8th when you have 4 there??

Comment: doesn't it mean select EVERY 4th?

Comment: no:  http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.mydiv ul li:nth-child(4n)').addClass("nth");
```

pay attention to the `4n`